# Generating unique ids from a custom place-value notation for a URL Shortener

Tags: php, database, data-structures, number-formatting

I want to make a URL shortener that has this URL format:
**http://myurlshortner.com/{id}**

Where the **id** is unique and generated from the following place-value notation sequence/system/series:

```
0
1
2
.
.
.
9
a
b
c
.
.
.
z
```

For example: **http://myurlshortner.com/1b6z**

For saving the entry to database, I want to make **id** the primary key(or unique field) that increments with every new entry and follows the above mentioned sequence. How can I do this?

For data storage, I will use Amazon SimpleDB. So there won't be any stored procedures or other DBMS functionality like there are in MySQL that I can use.

This is exactly(almost) like how URL shortners like http://tinyurl.com and http://bit.ly work.

...and I am coding in PHP. I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by just converting a normal base 10 id to base 36.

Base 36 uses the numerals 0-9 and then the letters A-Z.

You can do the conversion before storing it in the database and use the converted number as the id, or just use a normal base 10 auto increment and do the conversion in your code.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

```
php > echo base_convert(123456789, 10, 36);
21i3v9
```